# My textinput in react native blurs directly after focus

Tags: react-native, uitextinput

I have two forms in react-native. One of the works perfectly, the other (in another component) has a bug. The `TextInput`s in the form keep blurring when getting focus.

The video I made (see gif below) shows that whenever I click in the input it gets focus and then immediately blurs right after it.

The code for the input (now with debugs):

```
<TextInput value={group.name}
    blurOnSubmit={false}
    onBlur={() => console.log('I blur')}
    onFocus={() => console.log('I focus')}
    autoFocus={true} style={styles.textInput} />
```

[image: Everytime I click the input it focusses and blurs]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer... and I am confused as to why it is the answer, but here we go:

Apparently when you render a `TextInput` inside of a `TabBarIOS` component and you set `selected={true}` on your tab it will make it impossible to type into the TextInputs. I have no idea why. I had this on `true` in order to not have to click on the tab every time while building my views. I guess I will just set the default differently then :)

Answer (score 2):

I just encountered the same issue. In my case the problem was that my TextInput was a child of `<TouchableWithoutFeedback onPress={Keyboard.dismiss}>`. Removing this component all together fixed the issue.

Answer (score -2):

**Installation

1. Install React Navigation

   npm install react-navigation
2. Install Dependencies

   expo install react-native-gesture-handler react-native-reanimated react-native-screens react-native-safe-area-context @react-native-community/masked-view
3. Install React Navigation Stack

   npm install react-navigation-stack @react-native-community/masked-view